# Асинхронное чтение данных с сервера

Tags: c++, winapi, winsock, асинхронность

Какой самый удобный способ (С++) для асинхронного чтения постоянно приходящих с сервера данных? Платформа Windows.

Если есть возможность, хотелось бы увидеть схематичный пример (или линк на существующий). Простота реализации в данном случае важнее быстродействия.
Нативные средства языка (про boost знаю) предпочтительней

Comment: Простота и асинхронность — понятия не очень совместимые. Можно поинтересоваться, зачем вам именно асинхронное чтение?

Comment: Возьмите node.js

Comment: @andreymal, так как данные приходят без запросов к серверу, и неизвестно, когда именно

Comment: Ваш вопрос не понятен, уточните удобство в чем вас интресует.